# how to un-flat out SVN tags into branch commits?

Tags: svn, continuous-integration

I have a project running as the following layout:

```
/my_proj/trunk/
/my_proj/tags/1.0.0/
/my_proj/tags/1.0.1/
/my_proj/tags/1.0.2/
/my_proj/tags/1.0.3/
```

so in `tags` dir there are freezed branches ready for release.

Now we introduced a CI server which is only capable of scanning a single dir, unlike the many dirs in `tags`.

So is it possible to un-flat out `tags` into a series of commits, something like:

```
/my_proj/branch/release
  commit 1: "ver 1.0.0"
  commit 2: "ver 1.0.1"
  commit 3: "ver 1.0.2"
  commit 4: "ver 1.0.3"
```

Comment: What CI application do you use? What is it's desired settings? There are ways to do what you want but devil is in the details.

Comment: @bahrep I am using [XCode CI](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/XcodeCIGuide) from Apple. I can only continuously scan commits, not new dirs. And I don't want to CI on the trunk (Too frequent changes)

Answer (score 0):

What about this (not fully tested):

From somewhere in your workdir, in bash

```
svn copy ^/trunk@1 ^/branches/rolling -m "Creating a rolling release branch"
svn co ^/branches/rolling
cd rolling
svn list ^/tags | xargs -I {} sh -c \
 "svn merge --accept theirs-full --ignore-ancestry ^/tags/{}; \
  svn ci -m \"ver {}\" \
  svn update \
 "
```

This is is a pseudo automatic script.
If you have few tag version, you'd better run the commands one by one (i.e. without passing through xargs)